# Insert into Access Database on button click (No errors but not working)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data a user inputs from a web form into an Access Database. I made the Access Database with the following fields (FName, LName, State, Address, Zip, Telephone) and put it in a folder called App_Data\Registrationinfo.mbd within my code files.

When a user comes to the website and goes to register for a conference coming this summer they are given the mentioned fields in textboxes, once they click continue there's a cross page posting with labels which verifies with the user that the information is correct. Then upon clicking the "Submit" button on the web form, the information they entered will be put into the Access Database. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm getting any errors at all and the proper page redirect is working when they click submit but the information is not being put into the database.

Note: This is being written in C# with a masterpage.
The table in Access is called UserInfo with only the fields FName and LName just to keep it simple.

> ```
> protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=U:\App_Data\Registrationinfo.mbd";
>         string cmdstr = "insert into UserInfo(FName, LName)values(?, ?)";
>
>         OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
>         OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
>         con.Open();
>         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", labelFirstName.Text);
>         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", labelLastName.Text);
>         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
>         con.Close();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=U:\App_Data\Registrationinfo.mbd";
        string cmdstr = "insert into UserInfo(FName, LName) values(@First, @Last)";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
        con.Open();
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", labelFirstName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", labelLastName.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Name your parameters on this line:

```
string cmdstr = "insert into UserInfo(FName, LName) values(@First, @Last)";
```

And use Parameters.AddWithValues using the names:

```
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", labelFirstName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", labelLastName.Text);
```

Comment: If you're just going to copy/paste a code block, consider adding comments / a summary to explain the change - eg use named parameters instead of `?` placeholders...

Comment: Now I'm getting an error
Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Overflow

the error is at this line.

com.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Maybe you are inserting values too wide for your columns (you have last defined as varchar(20) and are inserting a 21 character last name)

Comment: I feel so dumb now, it was field lengths! Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it assisted you.

Comment: WARNING: With ACE/Jet OLEDB the Parameter *names* are ignored. You must specify the Parameters *in the order that they appear in the SQL statement*. That's why so many examples of parameterized queries for ACE/Jet OLEDB use `?` instead of named parameters.